# 144hz from DisplayPort through USB Type B

Tags: displayport, kvm-switch, docking-station

So I'm thinking of purchasing below KVM-switch/docking station to be able to switch between my gaming PC and work laptop:

https://www.startech.com/en-us/cards-adapters/usb3ddockft

I have a FHD monitor that runs at 144hz (G-SYNC) over DisplayPort, as you can see from the product pictures/description the connection between the switch and my two computers is carried out through **USB Type-B (9 pin) USB 3.0** and I'm wondering if I would still maintain the refresh rate through this connection?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you should ask [Startech sales support](https://www.startech.com/en-us/support/form#customer) for your particular setup. But just by looking at the specs it might not work the way you want, because it is going to cap the refresh rate to 30Hz

Comment: You do understand if you were to use that device, your monitor, would not longer be detected as a G-Sync compatible device?

Comment: I did actually not know that. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That dock product is built around a proprietary technology called "DisplayLink" (note: Display*Link* is very different from Display*Port*). Display*Link* requires you to install a proprietary graphics driver on your host computers so that the output of the computer's GPU can be compressed with the proprietary DisplayLink codec so it can be sent over USB 3.x to the DisplayLink chip in the dock which decompresses it and sends it out over HDMI or DisplayPort.

As to whether the DisplayLink technology in general, or the specific DisplayLink chip in that dock in particular, will support 144Hz and G-SYNC is a question for the product vendor. DisplayLink is proprietary and not well documented publicly, and I believe the technology has evolved over time, so there's no easy way for outsiders like us to say exactly what that product is capable of. You need to ask the vendor.

In general, even the folks behind DisplayLink don't recommend it for anything more than "casual" gaming. So since you're asking about 144Hz and G-SYNC like "serious" gamers tend to do, it's probably not the product for you.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation man. Testing it out myself would be the best to do. I promise to come back here with answers. I ordered one with free return policy from a local retailers.

Comment: So I'm back here with some answers after testing things out as I promised. The StarTech KVM (mentioned in my original question above) would only deliver a maximum of 120hz. Worth to mention that while using that KVM I was never able to open NVIDIA control panel, as if the KVM placed itself as an acting graphics layer above my Geforce RTX. Interestingly enough I tested out another 2-port DP switch from https://www.tendak.com/ and it's working wonders! Not having a single issue connecting my all Razer peripherals (keyboard, mouse, mousemat, headset, webcam, mic). I had to use a hub of course.

Comment: @EliyaAmanoeel Yeah, DisplayLink is garbage. You should never have to install drivers that create a special graphics layer just to use a KVM. The switch you bought from Tendak is almost certainly a more conventional KVM without the problems inherent in DisplayLink.